# Simple Liberty reserve PHP script for registration form

Tags: php, forms, registration

Hi I'm designing a script for someone that wants to have an online registration form where people can sign up for a certain event. There is also a cost to attend the event. So I need to have something where they can pay online. liberty reserve seems like the easiest way to do this. Can somebody show me how to design a script that forwards the person to liberty reserve to pay for the item and then sends them back to the website after they have paid? Thanks .

Comment: Just start reading TFM (the fine manual). You asked the exact same question [about PayPal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491150/simple-paypal-php-script-for-registration-form), I have little hope you'll fare any better with this one. Nobody's going to code it for you!

Comment: lol. I'd like some to decode the matrix for me plz. complete code only. ta.

Comment: The tag 'plz-send-me-the-codez' is missing in this question.

Comment: Ưhy don't we create that tag?

Answer (score 1):

I understand where you are coming from. Some of the comments are a little harsh.

I first used computers and then started wring code for web sites. As a computer user you have nice interfaces and widgets and gadgets to make the computer do things.

When I first started programming I was surprised that there wasn't a 'Make Online Shop' button in Dreamweaver.

"Oh! Do I really have to do *all that* just to do *this*!"

Years later, I am still improving my online payment system.

The answer to this question is:

- Expect things to take longer/involve more work than you first anticipate
- Expect to have to investigate / read up about your 'problem domain' and ideas for solutions.
- Keep learning about web programming

See: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1283582472&sr=1-1

or
 - Buy a solution or get someone else to do it

See: http://www.mrsite.com/sample_websites.asp

Answer (score 1):

Their website will practically make the code for you:

http://www.libertyreserve.com/en/help/merchants/payment-form-generator/

Comment: That really just makes this question EXTRA special!